# How to create Page variant Selection rule "if URL contains"?

Tags: 7

I want my variant to apply to all pages if the URL contains a certain string, eg: "cars".

So the cars variant should apply to `cars`, `cars/toyota`, `cars/toyota/camry`, etc.

Is there a way to use a wild card (`cars/*`?)?

I can't find any documentation on this.

Thanks

Comment: if "cars" is a contentype, is easy, just in panels selection rules, apply node:type="cars"

Comment: * should work. Try under Variant -> Selection rules, in the pulldown Select:URL Path then Add. In the new dialog box, select "Allow access to the following pages" then enter "cars/*" in the textarea, then save. According the description below the textarea which says: `The '*' character is a wildcard. Example paths are blog for the blog page and blog/* for every personal blog.`

Comment: The question lacks of context to provide accurate answer because there are several possibilities to build up url ... and this usually happen in views, panel or page manager ... and the answer will change, please elaborate about what you are trying to do with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/*` works. The issue I was having was I was separating them by  commas, where's they had to be separated by line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try under Variant -> Selection rules, in the pulldown Select:URL Path then Add. In the new dialog box, select "Allow access to the following pages" then enter "cars/*" in the textarea, then save. According the description below the textarea which says

```
The '*' character is a wildcard. Example paths are blog for the blog page and blog/* for every personal blog.
```